# How to invoke an SWT GUI from another class?

Tags: user-interface, constructor, swt, invoke

Back when I was using Swing I able able to do something like this..

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
public void run() { 
gui = new GUI();
gui.setVisible(true); 
}
}
```

Now I am using SWT and I am trying to create a GUI using the same fashion. Either the gui won't show up or the gui will freeze up. I am trying to call this from another class because I am developing this as a module for an entire application.

This is how I've tried so far..

```
gui = new GUI();
gui.open();
```

I have also tried with the brackets above but I have had no luck.

Here is the gui class

```
package org.eclipse.swt.snippets;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class GUI {

protected Shell shell;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        GUI window = new GUI();
        window.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Open the window.
 */
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Create contents of the window.
 */
protected void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");

}

}
```

I have tried editing the gui class to form a constructor but still no luck

Comment: Pardon, but did anyone get a properly working solution? I'm new at SWT, can't seem to figure it out... I'm trying to start the GUI from the controller class... [ Yes, I'll start my own question if no one answers or if I won't find the answer around here ]

Comment: FWIW: My working code exists here (It was written quite a while ago)

https://github.com/Sovietaced/Avior/blob/master/src/view/Gui.java

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is coming from `shell = new Shell()`. As far as I remember, the Display has to passed to the Shell constructor so it knows where to attach.

I would change it to something like this and try it:

```
/**
 * Open the window.
 */
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents(display);
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Create contents of the window.
 */
protected void createContents(Display display) {
    shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");
```

I don't have Eclipse or SWT on this machine, though, so I can't test it and am going off memory of how the SWT hierarchy works.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help anything. Remember that I'm using the window builder to generate the code so it should be pretty clean. I kept working and got some minor headway with help from Chris.

Th

The gui pops up, in a new thread now, and I can type in the text box that I inserted. Problem is, once I try to close the box the whole thing just freezes up and I need to force quit so something is still acting funky. I don't believe I should have to implement some type of window closing listener so I'm just confused.

Comment: Code as of now

gui class : http://pastebin.com/8F4ZyWwT

With constructor call like so


  System.out.println("About to call the constructor - cpanel");

  GUI gui = new GUI();

Comment: Ran the change above on my machine and it worked fine. Launched the GUI, was able to type in the box, and was able to close without issue. Here's a gist of the exact code I used: [gist](https://gist.github.com/2591511).